# FMU Generation in Adams to co-simulate with MATLAB ERROR

Tags: matlab, simulink, fmi

When I try to Export an Adams 2013.2 Model as a .fmu file for co-simulation I get an error that reads: "ERROR:   A problem occured while generating FMU. The FMU file is not generated proplerly."

I have tried changing variables around but to no avail. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Can you export any model from Adams?

Comment: Yes, I am able to Export Easy5 and MATLAB files.

Comment: No I mean can you export any model as a FMU? Maybe the adams documentation had a simple example that works? Otherwise it sounds like a question for Adams' support

Comment: The example on Adams documentation is for a MATLAB .m file export. They have no example to export an Adams file as an .fmu file. However, I am able to export a similar model in Modelica as an .fmu file.

Comment: Sounds like a case for Adams support